# is good to try to cast void* to nullptr?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to keep various `void*` stored, and want some of them to be `nullptr` if were not initialized. The thing is that I will need to now if they are `nullptr` or not.

I have made the next program:

```
#incldue <iostream>

int main() {
    void * a = nullptr;
    if (a == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "Yes" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "No" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

where 'Yes' will be printed, so it means that I gonna be able to figure out if the `void*` are `nullptr`, but I am not very sure if this is a good way to do that or it's better to use, for example, optionals. Is something wrong about what am I doing, or is there something that could lead to errors about doing that in this way?

Comment: Why do you expect `nullptr` to have a different behaviour with `void*`  than with other pointer types?

Comment: [I suspect you are in X-Y territory](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). In C++ you almost never want to store things without their type, and that's exactly what you're doing when you store `void` pointers. There will be a better way just about every time. If you get stuck figuring out that better way, ask a question and we'll help.

Comment: Dont use `void*`.  Use `std::variant` if your list of types to support is constrained or `std::any` if you need to support any type

Comment: The code works in the way you describe it, but as mentioned above, `void*` is a huge code smell outside of interfacing with C libraries and some rather advanced/specific applications like implementing type-erasure for e.g. `std::any`/`std::function` and similar..

Comment: I use `void*` all the time, for interop with C APIs that use `void*`.  Like for callback data, or for parameter passing, or function returns.  I try hard to keep the `void*`-ness at the interface edge, and cast to the correct type as soon as I can on the C++ side of the API.

Comment: @user17732522 comment removed, I should not comment before I finished my first coffee of the day ;)

Comment: Stay away from `void*` whenever you can. The typesystem exists to *help* you, don't subvert it.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying to do is determine whether a `void*` has been initialized, use `optional<void*>`.  The problem is that when converting the `nullptr` to a `void*`, you lose the information that it was initialized from a `nullptr`, as opposed to some other "null" pointer of a different type.

That said, I agree with the comments that there are usually better ways to implement type erasure than `void*`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What am I trying to do is more likely to have various of this pointers, and in some point look at them to see if are `nullptr`, rather that knowing if they were initialized like one, I explain myself?

Comment: In that case, you can just compare the ```void*``` to ```NULL```.   If you assign ```nullptr``` to a ```void*```, you'll get a ```void*``` that converts to 0 (a.k.a. ```NULL```) when converted to an integer.  This isn't the modern C++ way of doing things, but if you're stuck with ```void*``` I think this is the way to go.